# Why my UIViewController's view is being unloaded when visible?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, viewdidunload

This issue never happened to me. I have an UIViewController inside an UINavigationController. When a memory warning is received (nevermind the level), the `viewDidUnload` method of the **visible** controller is called, so the view is unloaded and I get an awesome black screen (with a navigation bar at the top).

I'm testing with an iPad 1 on iOS 4.3.3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the "views" property of the nav controller look like when you get this warning (ie what is in it, the order etc)? Also, in your viewDidUnload, add log NSLog(@"WINDOW: %@", self.view.window)" - that will tell you if in fact that view is visible.

Comment: Is this a "real" warning or one you simulated?

Comment: David, it is a real one.

Comment: are you calling [super viewDidUnload]; ?

Comment: only on your child view controller, not the nav controller?

Comment: Yes, the unloaded view is the contained in the nav controller

Comment: Is your viewcontroller hierarchy valid? How were all of your controllers added to the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the `viewDidUnload` method is called by `didRecieveMemoryWarning` function in the `UIViewController` (the super class). Basically iOS gives you couple of warnings and expect to see your memory usage go down. If you continue to ignore these, OS will kill your app.

Sometimes, though, it is critical to keep some views up and running so the way I get around this is to simply override the `didRecieveMemoryWarning` method and inside it, don't do anything.

Or better yet, check if `self` is the current view in the `self.navigationController.visibleViewController`, and if so, don't pass the memory warning call down to `[super didRecieveMemoryWarning]`.

If you are holding image caches or something, just empty those instead.

HTH

Comment: Quick note, iOS6 has changed this behavior now. UIViewController does not automatically call `viewDidUnload` on a memory warning by default anymore. It just calls the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method and that's it. Only iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

According to `Apple` memory management guidelines when a `viewcontroller` recieves memory warnings in critical situations it directly calls `viewDidUnload` so that memory can be managed by releasing the view.

Its actually ios providing chance to purge your temporary data which wil be useful while recreating the view. Since your `UIViewCotroller` is the root `viewcontroller` of the `navigationcontroller` you see oly navigationbar the view gets unloaded.

Comment: @emenegro See this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10), section 'Understanding How Views Are Loaded and Unloaded ' **bold** Figure 4-2 **bold**  shows how views are unloaded when ViewController receives memory warning.Also its explanation above the figure.

Comment: I saw these docs time ago and I don't see anywhere what is the exceptional situation in wich a visible view can be unloaded. Those docs explains how a view is unloaded and, C&P from steps of unloading cycle: "If the view cannot be safely released (for example, it is visible onscreen)...". So I want to know if it's possible to get a view unloaded while visible, in this case being inside a navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

You receive viewDidUnload in low memory situation on controllers, where iOS has determined that the views are not longer needed. Remember that Apple made some improvements on the implementations on later versions of iOS, so it might be worse seeing what happens under 5.x. Second you should review your view controller hierarchy.